# Can a Banner Advertisement Make My Site be Marked as Spam?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, backlinks, advertising

I have one blogging site called A with about 80000+ pages in it. It's doing good in Google Search. I have recently launched a new site called B. I have put a banner advertisement on my site A which has 80000+ pages.

I can see in SEMrush that it's showing about 25k+ backlinks from my site A. My question is since there will be 80K+ links from my website A to website B, can it hurt my Site reputation in Google Search for site A?

What is the best way to handle the situation? **I want keep advertising Site B but I do not want hurt my reputation in Google search**. Let me know if anyone here can suggest the best way to handle the situation.

Comment: I'm not qualified to answer this, but presumably having the links as "nofollow" would go some way towards addressing your converns.

Comment: I agree, such a large-scale dofollow links will not result in anything good.

Comment: I am not doing this for get link juice on website B, I am doing it for make some extra sales in SITE B since I have large audience in SITE A.

Comment: Davidgo is correct. The way to solve this is to add a "nowfollow" tag on the links on site A pointing to site B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SEO-in TOP provides a correct answer. However, I want to clarify a few things. You should use `rel sponsored` because it was introduced specifically to mark links that are advertisements or paid placements.

According to [Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/qualify-outbound-links):

> The nofollow attribute was previously recommended for these types of
> links and is still an acceptable way to flag them, though sponsored is
> preferred.

So you'll want:

```html
<a rel="sponsored" href="https://example.com/advertisement">The Advertisement</a>
```

I would also not be concerned about this large number of followed links under this context. Here are some reasons for this belief:

- The links will not have anchor text nor exist in the main body content of the page. Thus, the followed link would not carry a lot of weight in the first place.
- The links will most likely just be ignored.By 2023 Google understands what a banner ad is, and you haven't done anything wrong.

A context that you might be concerned about this is if the links were from sites that are part of a suspicious PLN. Something black hat would have to be going on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. :)

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

The probability of imposing sanctions for a single case of a large number of links from one site is minimal. If the site from which the link comes is not SPAM.

Still, it's very doubtful...

If your site has a page "About site advertising" where there is minimal information that you sell banner advertising on the site, but when analyzed manually - no one will impose sanctions on you.

In order to protect yourself in the future and exclude the possibility of imposing sanctions, you can close the link with the tag sponsored.

Closing the link with the tag noffolow will not give you the right result.

Closing the link with the noindex tag is the same. More than once I have seen how spam areas of the site were closed with the noindex tag and still be sanctioned. That is, Google does not perceive the content located in the noindex tag until there is no SPAM in it.